# Remove Photoshop Extended and use Normal Version?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, license, software-activation

We asked the Adobe Support about this Problem, but all they said was that we need to call the local Adobe support, but at this time nobody is there...

so we facing the following problem: We had a Photoshop CS5 Extended Trial Installed before, and now want to licence a Photoshop CS5 Normal Version. (Yes yes we have a valid serial etc...)

The Problem now seems to be, that, unless we removed and installed PS several Times, always the Extended Version seems to be installed!
Because of this we always get the Error Message:

```
The Serial Number is invalid for this product
```

Anyone knows a workarround for this??

Answer (score 0):

Somehow treats Adobe the Extended Version higher than the normal, and even if you have deinstalled the extended version, its still in the PCD Database.

If you delete the whole database (Adobe PCD, caps and backup folder in Programs/Common Files/Adobe), its working very well. I dont know why Adobe does it that way but ok...